# How to dehumanize ago time from humanize strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to dehumanize a duration string as follows to get the actual utc timestamp?

For example: "1.hour.ago 25.minute.ago 1.second.ago" convert back Fri, 18 Oct 2019 16:09:10 UTC +00:00

the site info has it as "17h 21m 1s ago" need to convert it to db datetime utc i manage to do this:

```
"17h 21m 1s ago".gsub("h", '.hour.ago').gsub("m", '.minute.ago').gsub("s ago", '.second.ago')
# ==> "17.hour.ago 21.minute.ago 1.second.ago"
```

But how to remove the string portion and convert to method datetime? Trying datetime parse did not work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rails. `"1.hour.ago 25.minute.ago 1.second.ago"` is not how Rails or Ruby works, and it has nothing to do with the string `"17h 21m 1s ago"`. That string would be generated from a single call to `time_ago_in_words` with a single timestamp, not three separate duration objects, and the output from `time_ago_in_words` is totally different.

Comment: Of possible interest: `require 'matrix'; arr = "1.hour.ago 25.minute.ago 1.second.ago".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) #=> [1, 25, 1]; time_in_seconds = Vector[*arr].inner_product Vector[3600, 60, 1] #=> 5105`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland without the added dependency `arr.zip([3600,60,1]).reduce(0) {|m, a| m += a.reduce(:*)
}`

Comment: What is `"1.hour.ago 25.minute.ago 1.second.ago"`? You probably don't have to parse a string like that, do you?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `"17h 21m 1s ago"` format is what you're working with, then you can use `Time#advance` to get the job done:

```
def when_was(string)
  time = Time.now.utc

  string.split(/\s+/).each do |part|
    case (part)
    when /\A(\d+)h\z/
      time = time.advance(hours: -$1.to_i)
    when /\A(\d+)m\z/
      time = time.advance(minutes: -$1.to_i)
    when /\A(\d+)s\z/
      time = time.advance(seconds: -$1.to_i)
    end
  end

  time
end

p when_was("17h 21m 1s ago")
# => 2019-10-18 01:31:36 UTC
```

You can also do this with `Time.now.utc - 17.hours - 21.minutes - 1.second` but that involves dynamic dispatching with `send` so it's more messy.

Comment: Assuming order you could go with `time.advance(string.match(/(?:(?<days>\d+)d\s)?(?:(?<hours>\d+)h\s)?(?:(?<minutes>\d+)m\s)?(?:(?<seconds>\d+)s)/).named_captures.transform_values {|v| -v.to_i})` rather than a case statement

Comment: @engineersmnky I bet you could! That's an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 2):

A prepackaged solution using [chronic_duration](https://github.com/henrypoydar/chronic_duration) gem:

```
require 'chronic_duration'

time_in_seconds = ChronicDuration.parse('17h 21m 1s ago')

p Time.now - time_in_seconds # => 2019-10-18 03:50:47 +0200
```

It can understand `m`, `min`, etc out of the box.

Comment: Will `ChronicDuration::parse` take the argument `"1.hour.ago 25.minute.ago 1.second.ago"`? If not you obviously have to do a simple conversion. I trust that this method is less likely to return false positives (returning time in seconds when the argument clearly does not represent a time) than the notorious method `Date::parse`: `Date.parse "I may go to the opera, you?" #=> #<Date: 2019-05-01 ((2458605j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: No, it gets confused by the dots between the numerals and time units. You need to use `Time.now - ChronicDuration.parse("17.hour.ago 21.minute.ago 1.second.ago".gsub(/\./, ' '))`

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that in your answer, rather than in a comment, as `"1.hour.ago 25.minute.ago 1.second.ago"` is presumably a given.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the hours, minutes and seconds are sequential.

```
time_in_string = "1.hour.ago 25.minute.ago 1.second.ago"
time_info = time_in_string.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
#=> [1, 25, 1]
time_in_seconds = time_info.zip([3600, 60, 1]).sum{ |x, y| x * y }
=> 5101
Time.now
#=> 2019-10-18 22:56:14 +0300
Time.now - time_in_seconds.seconds
#=> 2019-10-18 21:31:13 +0300
```

As a method:

```
def time_from_string(time_in_string)
  time_info = time_in_string.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
  time_in_seconds = time_info.zip([3600, 60, 1]).sum{ |x, y| x * y }
  Time.now - time_in_seconds.seconds
end

p time_from_string(time_in_string)
#=> 2019-10-18 21:37:10 +0300
```